# JS Trouble iterating over an HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html, django

This should be pretty straight forward. I have a loop, which works, and a variable collecting html code with getElementsByClassName.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputfile');
if (inputs)
    console.log(inputs);
```

Output

```
HTMLCollection []
    0: <input id="id_avatar" class="inputfile" name="id_avatar" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" type="file">
    id_avatar: <input id="id_avatar" class="inputfile" name="id_avatar" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" type="file">
    length: 1
```

It successfully finds the html piece I'm looking for.

Next I try to feed it through a loop.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
    console.log("running");
    var label    = input.nextElementSibling,
        labelVal = label.innerHTML;
});
```

This does not work. The loop is completely looked over, and is never executed. However if I feed

```
var herp = ["1"];
```

into the loop, I will see the console print log "running". What is going on? Var inputs is valid to iterate over. Why is it being ignored and/or treated as empty?

Other loops don't work either, for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log("Here we go");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried replicating your issue, but the code you provided works for me, check this snippet out:
https://jsfiddle.net/b7084pqm/

Comment: @Jahl this is bizarre. I cannot get it to execute the loop. I've tried in all different browsers and nothing.

Comment: Agreed.
https://jsfiddle.net/45f87kng/7/

If you are wanting to convert your nodeList to an Array then remember to return the element. 

Also your `var herp = ['1']` is not using an `int` to reference the index of an item in your nodeList so that also might be causing you issues.

Comment: @stwilz the array is coming back empty.

Comment: @Sleepy-Z https://jsfiddle.net/stwilz/45f87kng/12/ . The text under the inputs should append the total amount of inputs.

Comment: @stwilz Still not working. When I add a console.log into the Array.prototype.map, it doesn't even appear. I have no idea what is wrong or why these Array.prototype.* aren't operating. I copied and pasted from Jsfiddle.

Comment: @Sleepy-Z it sounds like there is an issue outside of what you've described. Can you drop your broken code into JS fiddle and show what's not working?

Are you using any frameworks in your build? If you were rendering out these inputs from an array you might find that your code is running before the elements are rendered.